# Getting undefined when transforming data from REST API

Tags: node.js, express

On the code below I am tryint to transform the content iterating over it and choosing the properties I want, but Im getting undefined on some of them and I can't figure out why.

**transformContent.js**

```
(function () {

  let contentService = require('./contentService'),
    moment = require('moment'),
    _ = require('lodash');


  exports.transformedContent = () => {
    let data = [];
 // trying to spread the content to iterate over
    let info = [{ ...contentService.getContent }];


    // iterate over info
    for (let i of info) {
      let ticketInfo = i.TicketInfo;
      let imageThumb = _.find(ticketInfo.ImageList, ['Type', 'S']); // getting undefined ???
      let imageFull = _.find(ticketInfo.ImageList, ['Type', 'L']);
      let availableModality = i.AvailableModality;
      let modalities = [];

      // iterate over availableModality
      for (let a of availableModality) {
        let price = _.find(a.PriceList, ['Description', 'SERVICE PRICE']);
        let dates = [];

        // iterate over operation date list
        for (let date of a.OperationDateList) {
          let operationDate = moment(date.Date, 'YYYYMMDD');
          let from = operationDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
          let to = operationDate.add(date.MaximumDuration, 'days').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
          let days = {
            From: from,
            To: to
          };
          dates.push(days);
        }

        let modality = {
          Code: a.Code,
          Name: a.Name,
          Contract: a.Contract.Name,
          PriceList: parseFloat(price.Amount.toFixed(2)),
          OperationDateList: dates
        }
        modalities.push(modality);
      }

      // (T)ransformed response
      responseT = {
        Destination: ticketInfo.Destination.Code,
        Code: ticketInfo.Code,
        Classification: ticketInfo.Classification.Value,
        Name: ticketInfo.Name,
        Description: ticketInfo.DescriptionList[0].Value,
        ImageThumb: imageThumb.Url,
        ImageFull: imageFull.Url,
        AvailableModality: modalities
      }
      data.push(responseT)
    }
    return data;
  }
})()
```

I get the content from an API on this code/file below.

**contentService.js**

```
(function () {
  'use strict'

  let request = require('request'),
    config = require('../config');


  function getOptions(req) {
    let token = config.getToken();
    let options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://travellogix.api.test.conceptsol.com/api/Ticket/Search',
      body: JSON.stringify(req.body),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
      }
    };
    return options;
  }

  exports.getContent = function (req, res) {
    let token = config.getToken();
    let options = getOptions(req);
    console.log('getContentOptions', options);
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      console.log('status', response.statusCode);
      if (!error && (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201)) {
        let content = JSON.parse(body);
        res.send(content);
      } else {
        return res.status(502).send({ error: error, message: 'There was an error during Service API request.' });
      }
    });
  }

})()
```

To get this content I need to authenticated with a Service API, and I am doing this with the file/code below:

**authService.js**

```
(function () {

  let request = require('request'),
    config = require('../config');

  let initialTime = null;

  const handleTokenTime = (initialTime) => {
    let currentTime = new Date();
    if (currentTime.getTime() - initialTime.getTime() > config.expiringTokenMilisec) {
      console.log('Token time has exceeded!')
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log('Token time is ok!')
      return false;
    }
  }

  let tokenOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://travellogix.api.test.conceptsol.com/Token',
    body: config.password
  };

  exports.checkForToken = (req, res, next) => {

    function setToken(error, response, body) {

      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        let info = JSON.parse(body);
        initialTime = new Date();
        // set access_token to token
        config.setToken(info.access_token);
        return next();
      } else {
        return res.status(502).send({ error: error, message: 'It was not possible to authenticate with the Service API.' });
      }
    }

    if (config.getToken() == null || handleTokenTime(initialTime)) {
      request(tokenOptions, setToken);
    } else {
      next();
    }
  };

  exports.getToken = function () {
    return config.getToken();
  };

})()
```

my express.js has the code below on it:

```
(function () {

  'use strict'

  // Set the 'NODE_ENV' variable
  process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

  console.log("process.env.NODE_ENV", process.env.NODE_ENV);

  let express = require('express'),
    request = require('request'),
    config = require('./config'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    authService = require('./services/authService'),
    transformContent = require('./services/transformContent'),
    logger = require('morgan');

  let app = express();
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

  // Use the 'NODE_ENV' variable to activate the 'morgan' logger or not
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    app.use(logger('dev'));
  }

  // Routing - If it gets bigger, put in a different file or directory called routes
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {

    app.route('/')
      .post(authService.checkForToken, transformContent.transformedContent);

    app.route('/failauth')
      .post(transformContent.transformedContent);

    app.route('/auth')
      .post(authService.checkForToken, function (req, res) {
        let token = config.getToken();
        res.send({ token: token });
      });

  } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.route('/')
      .post(authService.checkForToken, transformContent.transformedContent);
  }


  app.listen(3003, function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port 3003');
  });

})()
```

And there is also a development.js file to get build the token access.

```
(function () {
    'use strict'
    var token = null;

    module.exports = {
        password: 'grant_type=password&username=test1%40test2.com&password=Aa234567%21',
        expiringTokenMilisec: 86000 * 1000, //almost 24hours,
        token: null,
        getToken: function () { return token; },
        setToken: function (newToken) { token = newToken; }
    }

})()
```

the last file is a config file to mount the environment.

```
(function(){

    'use strict';
    // Load the correct configuration file according to the 'NODE_ENV' variable
    module.exports = require('./env/' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.js');

})()
```

The travel log expect to receive the payload input:

```
a) Header:

Content-Type application/json 

b) Body (request payload):

Raw json example:

{
"Language": "ENG", 
"Currency": "USD", 
"Destination": "MCO", 
"DateFrom": "11/26/2019", 
"DateTO": "11/29/2019", 
"Occupancy": { 
      "AdultCount": "1", 
      "ChildCount": "1", 
      "ChildAges": ["10"] 
  }
}
```

The output after transformed content should be:

```
[ { "Destination": "MCO", "Code": "WDWBASENXT", "Classification": "Theme & Aquatic Parks", "Name": "Disney Magic Your Way Base Ticket with No Expiration Option", "Description": "The Walt Disney World Resort is the place where fun reigns supreme and dreams come true every day. With four Theme Parks, two Water Parks plus Downtown Disney Area - where the most amazing shopping, dining and entertainment imaginable can be found. Discover an entire world of enchantment and wonder around every corner with one of Disney's Magic Your Way Tickets. Disney’s Magic Your Way Base Ticket offers admission to one of the following theme parks for each day of the ticket", "ImageThumb": "http://www.hotelbeds.com/giata/extras/small/ds/28917/28917_3.jpg", "ImageFull": "http://www.hotelbeds.com/giata/extras/big/ds/28917/28917_3.jpg", "AvailableModality": [ { "Code": "0#CNX09/19", "Name": "3 Days", "Contract": "2015WDWEURTO", "ServicePrice": 656.08, "OperationDateList": [ { "From": "11/26/2015", // Date "To": "11/29/2015" // Date + MaximumDuration }, { "From": "11/27/2015", // Date "To": "11/30/2015" // Date + MaximumDuration } ] }, // ... (then loop) ] }, // ... (Then loop) ]
```

How can I validate the content to not get undefined and be able to iterate over it to? What am I missing? I've been trying for almost 15 hours straight and couldn't find the proper way to access it and grab just what I want.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I suggest that you try to produce a minimal example and add samples of input as well as expected and actual outcomes. This makes getting help much faster.

Comment: I looked into your code a bit. First of all, you must figure out how to use express. In `transformedContent` you are trying to spread a function that looks like an express handler. That's why you get the error - but the actual problem is in your program structure.

Comment: I'll have a look, Sami. I'll try to look for something and change the structure. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK going to try and get this straightened out. Your app structure is a little strange, maybe check out the express docs at some point. You definitely don't need to wrap everything in IIFE's like you are doing. I've forked it over to my machine and am working through the routes. Currently, I'm working with your `POST /` route. This is the response that comes back once I edited some things to get all the syntax errors and undefined errors out:

```
"response": {
        "statusCode": 400,
        "body": "{\"code\":null,\"message\":\"The Language field is required., The Currency field is required., The Destination field is required., The DateFrom field is required., The DateTo field is required., The Occupancy field is required.\",\"developerMessage\":\"Source: , StackTrace:\"}",
        "headers": {
            "content-length": "267",
            "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "server": "Microsoft-IIS/8.0",
            "x-powered-by": "ASP.NET",
            "date": "Wed, 18 Dec 2019 07:41:38 GMT",
            "connection": "close"
        },
        "request": {
            "uri": {
                "protocol": "http:",
                "slashes": true,
                "auth": null,
                "host": "travellogix.api.test.conceptsol.com",
                "port": 80,
                "hostname": "travellogix.api.test.conceptsol.com",
                "hash": null,
                "search": null,
                "query": null,
                "pathname": "/api/Ticket/Search",
                "path": "/api/Ticket/Search",
                "href": "http://travellogix.api.test.conceptsol.com/api/Ticket/Search"
            },
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer 9cDDA-Uwz-NDVePPUWyFHegBKMfr7afmcxGPM7l_xOLggU2zI8hwpa7s4-r1MWr7Ip25zoijFP2wqV6VdFYYVI0mp5xwmSKVX4Mzsq_EfJMyrpGWADtRNv2e1_cmNZypw0P0EaIhTdsbgOdYykgGMEzS3jbnNSBlH_DiRewKxQBxUdhId4krbLD2drzORW6sX_cb2Y9Buib_2-IDIvpOKKs4uDhjs6hP1yjmKJ5QX5jy6F-3ctJJxc56oo7Pe4KUqeDSEefmC2-dSSYN42kPB6b6aTI8T5sjl0eNOzmVIkAbYYP_4bf8DMbzPCIWyUB4joBNIrIRK190OlWR5Q5FnShQhrc20dRAiJHE4G3hkaiWioPsxl1N5g77PMjPFR_Niaivt-4QQWlUruj7lBekc22dmTNqv5j4BzloMVv7fB8RPDAbP2ka0b293VdRTIPXg8JDmb5Z6SngNCZVVua7exVUj1fpRxIpSDYMxYj_MNZ_yBoIkHwYrxvR48yQLGfpr68dzZw0BlpPTnlUZsDTAQ",
                "content-length": 2
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm just making a call to `contentService.getContent` in your `transformContent.transformedContent` function at this route:

```
app.route('/')
    .post(authService.checkForToken, transformContent.transformedContent);
```

Which fires off a `POST http://travellogix.api.test.conceptsol.com/api/Ticket/Search'` request, where you will pass in the `req.body`, but I'm not sure what the proper values are. Can you post what this travellogix api expects to receive?

Comment: Thank you for your take. I still trying it and just edit the question with what the api expects.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for those who answered and took the time to review my code. I did some adjust base on what @Daniel.Schroeder @Sami Hult replied and with that I was able to fix the code.

Thank you guys again! I really appretiate that.